# Input breaks out of small container with flex basis auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When there's an outer div with `display: flex`, and inner div with `flex: 1 0 auto` and an input inside with `width: 100%`, the input breaks out of the container at a certain size. This is likely the default min size of an input, however setting `min-size: 0` does not fix it. Removing the flex basis auto does resolve it, but I'd like to know why (as the default flex basis value is auto anyway) and how it can be fixed still keeping flex basis and the current HTML structure as closely as possible.

[image: Input breaks out]

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xjh2635s/

```css
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the issue is the `flex:1 0` which mean `flex-shrink:0` .. remove it to allow the shrink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Removing the flex basis auto does resolve it, but I'd like to know why (as the default flex basis value is auto anyway). . .

You're correct that the initial value of `flex-basis` is `auto` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Specifications)).

However, in using the `flex` property, you've overridden the default, resulting in `flex-basis: 0`.

`flex: 1 0` means:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 0`
- `flex-basis: 0`

(Spec: [§ 7.1.1. Basic Values of Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Specifications))

So when you remove `flex-basis: auto` the code falls back to `flex-basis: 0`, and the layout works.

*Note that the problem you describe exists in Chrome, but not Firefox and Edge, where the layout works fine with the original code.*